# How can I delete an object flagged as SFGAO_STREAM?

Tags: c++, delphi, windows-shell

I have a file that I can reach by pidl via `IShellFolder`. This file has the flag `SFGAO_CANDELETE` and its parent folder has the flag `SFGAO_STORAGEANCESTOR` only.

How can I delete the file?

Conditions:

1. Files and folders are on USB device (digital camera and a phone).
2. A solution should work at least on WinXP (Win2000 support would be wonderful)
3. With no using of WPD.

I tried calling [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) on the pidl, but it requires a file-system path, not the GUID-style path I have. [I asked about this on Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/XP/Q_27319256.html), where I learned about [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx), but that requires Windows Vista.

Sample:

```
parent folder::
media ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#7&69f3c26&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,SECZ9519043CHOHB,12351995904}\{0000000C-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
SFGAO_CANCOPY
SFGAO_CANMOVE
SFGAO_CANRENAME
SFGAO_CANDELETE
SFGAO_HASPROPSHEET
SFGAO_DROPTARGET
SFGAO_STORAGEANCESTOR
SFGAO_FOLDER
SFGAO_HASSUBFOLDER
SFGAO_CONTENTSMASK

file to delete:
some breathing.mp3 ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#7&69f3c26&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,SECZ9519043CHOHB,12351995904}\{0000000C-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\{0000001B-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\{0000001C-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\{00000021-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
SFGAO_CANCOPY
SFGAO_CANMOVE
SFGAO_CANRENAME
SFGAO_CANDELETE
SFGAO_HASPROPSHEET
SFGAO_DROPTARGET
SFGAO_STREAM
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited this question to add some of what you learned from when you asked this on Experts Exchange. I've also removed your second question about getting the size and timestamps; it has nothing to do with how to delete the file. Please ask about that issue in a separate question and let this one focus solely on deletion. You'll get better answers to both questions that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the answer I posted](http://www.bcbjournal.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1207) to this very same question (from you?) on the C++Builder Journal forums last month.  In short, the only documented way I can find anywhere is to  retreive the parent folder's `IContextMenu` interface, and then invoke the `delete` verb on the desired file.

Comment: This is what I've found too. Building a custom data object and passing it to IFileOperation does even seem to work. There is magic in the "delete" verb it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Using the IContextMenu is completely bad idea, despite it could do work.

It is similar that when you want a cup of coffee you should call a man that comes into your home and do it for you.